# Sketching curves in the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

Well I really need your help here because I need to sketch the curve $|z-1|=1$ in the z-plane and then its image under the $w=z^{2}$ but the thing is that I dont know how to sketch that function.

In class we only chose a line and then we saw that $w$ only open its argument, we covered too  that when we have a circle it bend it like if we have a donut, **but I dont know how this  may helps.**

Well, the question is,  **how can I sketch this function and its image?**, **I am lost in this** :) thanks in advance for your help **I really need it**.

Comment: Download ComplexTool5.jar software, it's useful tool.

Comment: Thanks a lot Maryam but without that how can I do it ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your circle is parametrized by $\gamma(t) = 1 + \exp(it)$, so its image under squaring is parametrized by
$$
\gamma(t)^{2} = \bigl(1 + \exp(it)\bigr)^{2} = \dots.
$$
Alternatively, if you prefer to work with real vectors instead of complex numbers, you can write $\gamma(t) = (1 + \cos t, \sin t)$, and note/recall that squaring sends $(x, y)$ to $(x^{2} - y^{2}, 2xy)$.

Comment: thanks a lot @user86418 :) and like this I can do othe things like this isnt?

Comment: thanks a lot @user86418 :) and like this I can do otherthings like this isnt?

Comment: If I understand what you're asking, "yes". Specifically, if you can parametrize a curve as a pair of real functions, you can compose with holomorphic functions (exp, log, sin, cos, ...) and get a parametrization of the image curve. For instance, using "$\exp(x, y)=e^{x}\cos y, e^{x}\sin y)$", you could plot the image of your circle under exponentiation.

Comment: well I do not know what an holomorphic function is but the thing is that if I have to know which is the image of a line for example I parametrize by $\theta=\phi$ and then I squared it and do algebra to know what the image is inst?

Comment: Yes, if $\gamma$ parametrizes some curve $C$ (a line segment, a circle, whatever), and if $f$ maps the plane to the plane, then $f\circ\gamma$ parametrizes the image $f(C)$.

Comment: good but now I have a problem because how can I parametrize a vertical line I did it like $\theta=\pi /2$ but iy doe not help me

Comment: An arbitrary line in $\mathbf{C}$ is parametrized by $\gamma(t) = z_{0} + \alpha t$ for some complex numbers $z_{0}$ and $\alpha$, i.e., to $(x_{0} + at, y_{0} + bt)$ if $z_{0} = x_{0} + iy_{0}$ and $\alpha = a + bi$. A vertical line corresponds to $\alpha$ pure imaginary ($a = 0$). If that doesn't clarify, it may be best to ask a separate question...? :)

Comment: ok I will ask another question and I write here the link :), can you help with the new question?

Comment: I have asked another question and is right here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1124262/sketching-lines-and-curves-in-the-complex-plane