# sketching lines and curves in the complex plane.

Tags: complex-analysis

Well, my question is I a have the line equation x=1 and I need to know wich is thw image under $w=z^{2}$, then I parametrize it like $\theta=\pi /2$, the next step was to squred it $(\theta-\pi /2)^{2}=0$ but it is supposed that I have to get a parabola but how do I get from that expression the cosine and the excentricity, Can you help me please :) thanks alot in advance, because **I really need your help :**)

Answer (score 2):

The line $x = 1$ is parametrized by $\gamma(t) = 1 + it$, or, in real form, $(1, t)$.

The polar description $\theta = \pi/2$ is problematic for two reasons:

- It describes the imaginary axis (not the line $x = 1$).
- The complex squaring map in polar coordinates does not square $\theta$, but instead sends $re^{i\theta} \sim (r, \theta)$ to $r^{2} e^{2i\theta} \sim (r^{2}, 2\theta)$.

Comment: thanks a lot user86418 but how can I use that parametrization, well I think I have to squred it and do some algebra but do Am I missing something?

Comment: It's exactly the same as with your circle question: Plug the parametrization of the line into the complex squaring map. :) Have you tried that, and did you not get a parabola? Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your question/point(s) of confusion...?

Comment: I am asking only that if have to take the equation above squered it, do algebra and then yes get a parabola :) that is my question

Comment: I am imagine that the parabola you are talking about is the  [(1+ix)^2] right?

Comment: Yes, the parabola you want is parametrized by $\gamma(t)^{2} = (1 + it)^{2}$. (This is a complex-valued function, so its image is a plane curve, easily seen to be a parabola once you multiply out and collect the real and imaginary parts.)

Comment: thanks a lot :) and in general a line of the form $y=mx+b$ how can I parametrize it to do the same thing like in this exercise?

Comment: The case of general lines is answered in my comment on your other question ("...if this doesn't clarify, it may be best to ask a separate question"). If you'll forgive my presumption: The tone of many of your questions suggests you're anxious about memorizing formulas and algorithms, to the extent that you're not focusing on the common-sense reasons for computations. If that's true, you'll have a better time with math if you relax, and develop the confidence that you can figure out details on your own. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice :)